# ccfonts + standard math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, luatex, math-fonts

I would like to know if it is possible to use the Concrete font together with the standard LaTeX mathematical font. If it is possible, could someone please tell me how to do this? My thanks in advance!

Comment: And get something like [this picture  (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyPBI.png)? No, thanks.

Comment: Yes, to get something like that. I confess that I liked the appearance.

Comment: To everybody their taste. I'd never ever consider it.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is tagged `luatex` and `xetex`, I guess you compile with lualatex or xelatex.

You could try `\usepackage{concmath-otf}`.  You will get the Concrete text fonts in OpenType format. If you don't like the math font, you could switch back to anything else, f.i. Latin Modern adding

`\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`

Answer (score 0):

The whole concrete package looks like

```
\ProvidesPackage{concrete}[1996/10/08]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% CONCRETE.sty
%  Provides fonts for an approximation of the style in _Concrete Mathematics_.
% History.....................
%  96-10-08 Jim Hefferon jhefferon@smcvt.edu
%    It is an FAQ on comp.text.tex that people look on CTAN for a style 
%    with this name.  Seems reasonable.  They are always advised to 
%    \usepackage the two packages below.  So here is a wrapper style
%    to do that.
% Remarks.....................
% 96-10-08 jh
%   There are other styles for Concrete Math (concmath and something
%   from AMS-LaTeX 1.1 are the ones that I know of), but this one is
%   modular in that if the packages it calls are updated then of
%   course, this is updated also).  In particular, there are no font 
%   parameters, etc.
% Bugs........................
%  *Unlike the AMS-LaTeX v. 1.1 style file, this makes no attempt to
%  provide any grafitti, etc. macros.  Just the fonts.  (One could
%  argue that those are document-style, not font, macros.)
\RequirePackage{beton} % for the text fonts
\RequirePackage{euler} % for the math fonts
\endinput
```

This means if you just want to change the text font, you can directly use the `beton` package:

```
\usepackage{beton}
```

Comment: Also `T1` encoding or the fonts are bitmap.

Comment: @egreg With such a font combination, the result won't be much worse :)